# Four tags for economics is not very economic

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There are currently four tags for economics:

- [economy](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economy)
- [economics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economics)
- [economic-policy](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economic-policy)
- [intl-political-economy](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intl-political-economy)

Right now there are no real tag descriptions to differentiate.

It seems to me that they're all the same, and that they should be merged./

We could perhaps differentiate between economic policy ([economy-policy](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economy-policy)) and economic theory ([economic-theory](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economic-theory)), but the most important reason for tags is to connect experts with interesting questions to answer. I'm not sure if there are experts on economic policy that aren't also experts on the economic theory (or vice versa)?

Comment: You should add monetary and fiscal policy at the very least.

Comment: And maybe ones for Keynesianism and Supply-Side Economics while we are at it

Answer (score 3):

I would agree that this is too many tags. Although I would propose combining all of these into a single tag, whatever name it might use.

As far as your two-tag proposal, most questions about economic theory are not within scope here, and should probably be migrated to Economics.SE. The exception is macroeconomics.  According to our [Help](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Just to clarify, Macroeconomics is specifically on-topic. Most public policy questions involve economic matters, so if you just need to understand how an economic principle works, ask away!

Macroeconomics nearly always involves public policy anyway, so in practical terms I don't see this becoming a problem.

Additionally, I browsed around the questions under [economics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economics) and it looks to me like all of those have are related to policy, so perhaps the [economic-theory](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economic-theory) tag is not necessary at all.

Answer (score 0):

Economic policy & Economic theory are vastly different subjects: One deals with "What is", while the other deals with "What if".

1. Economic policy is about what a country's economic laws allow/restrict
2. Economic theory is about how a country's economic laws could be affecting it's GDP

     -
3. Experts on economic policy are called [Corporate lawyers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporate_lawyer).
4. Experts on the economic theory are called scientists/researchers ([Economist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_economists))